# Postgres: pg_restore cmd not restoring the data in my database

Tags: postgresql, prisma, pg-dump, pg-restore

I created a dump of my neon postgres db using this command: `pg_dump -Fc -v -d <source_database_connection_string> -f <dump_file_name>`. I renamed two of my misspelt columns in my prisma schema then proceeded to lose two columns of data due to a prisma db push command. My objective was to gain back this lost data using the `pg_restore` command. I tried changing the wrongly named columns in the feedback-upt.bak file to the updated names from my schema in notepad, then running the pg_restore command but that didn't work. I changed the columns back to their misspelt names in the backup.bak and re-ran the restore command but this didn't work either. Also note that I got these commands from neon.tech docs here: https://neon.tech/docs/import/import-from-postgres. This is what is returned in my bash:

```
$ pg_restore -v -d postgresql://xxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.us-east-2.aws.neon.tech/xxxxxxx?sslmode=require feedback-upt.bak
pg_restore: error: input file is too short (read 0, expected 5)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. The data that was lost was very essential.

Comment: 1) This `pg_dump -Fc` creates a custom(binary) format file. If you are directly editing that then you will get an error. 2) Try `pg_restore -t <the_table> -f the_table.sql`. This will create a plain text dump only the that table. Though it maybe that the binary file is in a corrupted state and the command will not succeed. Unless you have an original copy of `backup.bak` you may be out of luck.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately I only have one copy of the backup.bak and that's the one that I edited (corrupted).

Comment: 1) Unless you have an older backup, you could do a partial restore from, the data is lost. 2) FYI, never use Notepad on files you care about, text or otherwise.  3) Whenever tweaking a file format, for at least the first time, always work on a copy of that file. To be clear I know this because I have made the same mistake on more then one occasion(slow learner) and have the scars to prove it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. My last system restore point was from 4 days ago. That's too long of a period as I made alot of changes with other due to school. Is there anything else i can do?

Comment: 1) The lost columns and data was only on one table correct? Per my first  comment you can pull only that table out of the custom file and restore it. 2) Unless you can exactly undo the changes made to the binary file there is no much hope, especially as in my experience Notepad mangles even text files.

Comment: Correct. I exactly undid the changes that I made. How can i pull a column that's been spelt wrong and expect to get my data back in the correctly spelt one?

This is my command to pull restore data from one table:

```$ pg_restore -U postgres --data-only -d postgresql://xxxxxxx:xxxxxx@ep-holy-sky-a546g2ge.us-east-2.aws.neon.tech/xxxxxxxxx?sslmode=require -t Feedback feedback-upt.bak
pg_restore: warning: invalid creation date in header```

Do i enter the correctly spelt column name or the wrongly spelt one from my backup?

Comment: 1) Do not put code in comment add as text update to question text. 2) You did not exactly undo the changes, if you had you would not have a corrupted file. 3) I do not see the *.bak file in the pg_restore command. Also I would not restore directly to database(`-d`) I would do as I showed earlier restore to a file(`-f`). Then you can verify contents before using `psql` to restore the file contents to the database. 4) `--data-only` id not going to work if the table you are restoring to does not have the correct columns or the columns are not in the correct order.